# VisualStudio ShowAllCommands

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm looking for the equivalent of VSCode ShowAllCommands feature (Ctrl+Shift+P), but in VisualStudio (VS2019).

Is there a menu or a command to show "all commands" in Visual Studio 2019?

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to quickly find and execute a command in visual studio. But the accepted answer below helps you find a command.

Comment: I found this request on MS UserVoice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/19065082-add-ctrl-p-and-ctrl-shift-p-functionality-from-vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the shortcut on a random post on devblogs.microsoft.com.
With Visual Studio 2019 you can use : CTRL+Q

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes in Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard

It's not as clearly arranged as it is in VSCode, but it should do the job.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it answers my question, but it seems what i'm looking for does not exist in VisualStudio. I wanted a quick way to access and execute a command like in VSCode.